# Css3 tranform - повернуть вокруг нижней оси

Tags: css3, css

Скажите - как повернуть эту фигуру так - чтобы нижняя граница не двигалась вообще - то есть вокруг оси Х поворот происходил не по центру фигуры, а по ее низу.
http://cssdesk.com/BjR4A

Answer (score 1):

[transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

вот для webkit:

http://cssdesk.com/mM8NL

Comment: А чем трансформ от ориджина отличается? (перспектив который)

Comment: The perspective-origin CSS property determines the position the viewer is looking at. 

Это точка куда направлена камера сцены :)

The transform-origin CSS property lets you modify the origin for transformations of an element. 

Это точка относительно которой происходит трансформация.